# How to store result of c++ code compiling in a variable in bash?

Tags: c++, bash, variables

I want to store the errors(result) of a c++ file, when it is compiled.
I thought this code should store the result in the variable `var`

`var=$(g++ file.cpp)`

but when I ran this code it returned an empty variable.

Is there any way I can store the result of a c++ file compiling?

Comment: Is the output you want to store on stdout or on stderr?

Comment: The search you are looking for is probably "bash capture stderr"

Comment: You might need the error stream, like 2>/dev/null, but I have no idea on how to store this as a variable.

Comment: This is the answer https://www.configserverfirewall.com/linux-tutorials/bash-standard-error-variable/#:~:text=To%20store%20stderr%20into%20a%20variable%20we%20need%20to%20use%20command%20substitution.&text=But%2C%20by%20default%2C%20command%20substitution,stderr%20into%20the%20%24VAR%20variable.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to both bash and c++, didn't knew that, I'll close this question.